# Considering a specific name for the downloaded file

Tags: bash

I download a .tar.gz file using wget using this command:

```
wget hello.tar.gz
```

This is a part of a long script, sometimes when I want to download this file, an error occurs and when for the second time the file is downloaded the name of the downloaded file changes to something like this:

```
hello.tar.gz.2
```

the third time:

```
hello.tar.gz.3
```

How can I say that the whatever the name of the downloaded is, change it to `hello.tar.gz`?

In other words I don't want the name of the downloaded file be anything other than `hello.tar.gz`?

Comment: Take a look at `man wget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget hello.tar.gz -O <fileName>`

Comment: here `<fileName>` means the desired name I choose for the downloaded file? I mean the command should be like this: `wget hello.tar.gz -O hello.tar.gz` ?

Comment: Thanks, so this way the first file is overwritten, yes?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

wget have internal option like -r, -p to change default behavior
So just try the following:

```
wget -p <url>
wget -r <url>
```

Comment: after adding `-nc`, if I download the file for the 2nd time in the same directory, the first one will be overwritten? or what? If the file is not overwritten, this can not be my answer because in some cases the download of 1st file may be incomplete and this is why my script downloads the file for the 2nd time.

Comment: Sorry, -nc means enable file renaming (default behavior). try -p or -r options, they will overwrite existing single file

Answer (score 0):

Since now you noticed the incremental change. Discard any repeated files and rely on the following as initial condition:

```sh
wget hello.tar.gz
mv hello.tar.gz.2 hello.tar.gz
```

Comment: I don't know how may times the file can be created and I can't be sure it will be "hello.tar.gz.2" not "hello.tar.gz.3" .

Comment: Building upon @Manish answer, you can use:
`wget -O <file_name_you_want> <url_you_want>`

or:

`wget --output-document <file_name_you_want> <url_you_want>`